# ASA as a local DNS resolver

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, ipsec, dns

I have an site to site VPN access configured by ASAs. My remote site needs to connect to the domain through the tunnel which will required DNS located on the main site. I would like to use DNS server on the remote site assigned by local ISP for general query but redirect traffic for the domain though the tunnel to the Domain Controller/DNS.

Is it possible to do DNS resolver on the ASA so I do not need dns server on the remote site which will redirect domain requests to the main site.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The ASA (and IOS for that matter) DNS server is too simple ("primitive") for such a "complex" setup.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, ASAs do not support being used as a DNS server, even just as a forwarder.

Unless it is likely the two sites would get very different DNS results through their respective ISPs, you could just point all the clients towards the central site's DNS server. The actual browsing traffic would still use the local link, using whatever IP was returned by the central DNS.